# Failed to start, ddev-router failed to become ready, duplicate upstream

Tags: docker, nginx, drupal, ddev

I previously had a local drupal site working in ddev, then somehow the code got deleted with the ddev container remaining configured.

When I attempted to rebuild my local site, I set it up with a `local.` subdomain by setting the following in `.ddev/config.yaml`:

```
additional_hostnames:
- local.mysitename
```

Somehow in the process of re-configuring ddev I ended up with two ddev containers with the same name and the following error when I try to start the container.

```
Failed to start mysitename: ddev-router failed to become ready: logOutput=2019/03/19 22:29:32 [emerg] 15415#15415: duplicate upstream "local.mysitename.ddev.local-80" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:198
nginx: [emerg] duplicate upstream "local.mysitename.ddev.local-80" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:198
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed, err=container /ddev-router unhealthy: 2019/03/19 22:29:32 [emerg] 15415#15415: duplicate upstream "local.mysitename.ddev.local-80" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:198
nginx: [emerg] duplicate upstream "local.mysitename.ddev.local-80" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:198
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Removing the container from ddev and re-configuring it doesn't seem to help.

How can I remove both containers from ddev for good, or how do I at least resolve the error above?

Comment: The problem within your nginx configuration, the domain name is written twice maybe different include files

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the official solution is, but I got it "fixed" by:

1. Deleted the problem docker containers

   - Ran `docker ps -a` to list all docker containers
   - Ran `docker rm -f ID` where `ID` is the IDs of the docker containers named:

     - `ddev-mysitename-web`
     - `ddev-mysitename-dba`
     - `ddev-mysitename-db`
2. Reset Docker to factory defaults
3. Re-ran the ddev installer (Note I am on Windows btw)
4. Run `ddev start` on the site

Not ideal but what I did above is what fixed my issue.

Note: This will wipe the ddev DBs for all of your local sites

Comment: Good job! Next time, it's easy to` docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)` assuming there aren't any non-ddev containers you want to preserve.  Also remember that `ddev rm -a` will generally remove most things that need to be removed.

Comment: `ddev rm` was able to remove one of my duplicate sites, but when I tried to run it on the remaining site it complained that it couldn't find it.

I was aware of `docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)` but this removes ALL containers, no? I wasn't comfortable removing everything if I didn't need to.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the ddev-router container with `ddev poweroff`, then restarting DDEV to recreate the container worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me I could fix it after checking all my added `docker-compose-*.yaml` files.
It is important to check the hostname, the expose ports and the environments.
Since it is using Traefik in the background, the environment `HTTP_EXPOSE` must be set to the port I exposed otherwise it will take the default port, which in my cause would be `80` and the main project is also using `80` as the same port. This is why the router will tell me I have a duplicate upstream.

Also make sure to restart `ddev` as well as checking your volumes.